# Searching in a binary search tree - Explanation

Tags: binary-search-tree, logarithm

Suppose that we have numbers between 1 and 100 in a binary search tree and want to search for the number 55. Which of the following sequences CANNOT be the sequence of nodes examined?

```
A) 10, 75, 64, 43, 60, 57, 55

B) 90, 12, 68, 34, 62, 45, 55

C) 9, 85, 47, 68, 43, 57, 55

D) 79, 14, 72, 56, 16, 53, 55
```

Comment: I don't get your post, the explanation is on the link you posted. Explanation: In BST on right side of parent number should be greater than it, but in C after 47, 43 appears that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: C

Compare the key (55) with each element of the sequence.

a. is 55 greater than or less than 9 ?   -> it is **bigger** so go to the **right** and write 85

b. is 55 greater than or less than 85 ? -> it is **smaller** so go to the **left** and write 47

c. is 55 greater than or less than 47 ? -> it is **bigger** so go to the **right** 68

d. is 55 greater than or less than 68 ? -> it is **smaller** so go to the **left** and write 43

43 violate the binary search tree property
 (**left child is smaller than the parent and right child is bigger than the parent**)

43 is on the right subtree of 9        CORRECT

43 is on the left subtree of 85        CORRECT

43 is on the RIGHT subtree of 47      ****ERROR*****